# Facebook login button not redirecting on mobile devices

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm implementing a Facebook login button on my site via   ...I'm using the auth.login function in javascript SDK to redirect the users. On a desktop the user is prompted for a username and pass, and then is redirected to the page first.php...However, on mobile devices, the user is prompted to verify, but is then redirected to the facebook home page..I think this is because of my redirection method, can anybody offer some help?

Comment: I have a feeling it is in you app config.  Do you have all of the mobile app settings specified correctly?  Some people overlook the mobile settings section all together.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Because I don't require anything but basic access, I don't want the permissions dialog to popup, just the log in..What do you mean by mobile settings? I took a look, and they made it seem as if everything was cross-platform..For Now, I am including a PHP script that will dynamically tell if the user is on a mobile phone, and only then show both a registration and login link,which redirects to facebook and auth. dialog, as the regular button displays both...

Comment: I'm confused.  Can you post a link to the "auth dialog" documentation?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ I'm referring to the second image in that link. If I just have a login button and require no permissions , my user never has to click allow , or see that screen at all..

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the comments below the original question.  To use the authenticate dialog, you must have a Facebook application setup.  If you don't want a Facebook application, then you cannot use the authenticate dialog.  Remember, if you want to play in Facebook's sandbox, then you must play by their rules and not look for ways to "game the system".

So, to make it work on mobile devices, you must configure your application to work in the mobile environment. Go to your application settings and ensure you have the mobile part filled in correctly.

Comment: I just realized that I had Mobile Web URL, blank. However, I filled it in with the desired redirect uri and it's still not working ..There must be an easier way though, than using php to detect if it's a mobile device, and then to display a link to facebook auth

Comment: Since you've refused to give us examples of your code, or a live URL to look at, I don't think there's going to be much more we can help with.

Comment: I would except I'm working on a top secret project :) i solved the problem through a bit of a hack.. Thanks anyways!

Comment: We can only do so much with limited information.  I hope you understand.  Did configuring it as a mobile app help you?